# Can I include get_posts in this array?

Tags: query, get-posts, metabox

I am using the custom meta box script from deluxeblogtips.com and I wondered if I could include get_posts within this array so that it displays all posts within a set post type ("Locations" for example)

```
array(
        'name' => 'Location',    // File type: checkbox
        'id' => $prefix . location',
        'type' => 'checkbox',
        'desc' => 'Check this box to make any links open in a new browser window',
        'std' => 0                      // Value can be 0 or 1
    ),
```

Obviously I'd need to be able to select as many posts as I wanted.
 Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming there is an option in the array that is meant to receive an array of options for the checkboxes...?

In which case, you can use `get_posts` to obtain an array of post objects (of which ever type), and then loop through this, to create an array of post titles:

For example..

```
$args=array('numberposts'=>-1,'post_type' => 'location');
$post_objs = get_posts($args);
$options=array();

foreach($post_objs as $post_obj):
     $options[]=$post_obj->post_title;
endforeach;
```

You then have an array of location names, `$options` which you can feed into your metabox array.

*Disclaimer: I've not tested this code.*